# void *function() to call in main using the object of class in c++

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers, pass-by-reference

I want to call the void *function inside main using the object of the class

```
class SERVER{
   public: 
   void *handle_client(void *arg){
   ...
   }
};

int main(){
   SERVER s1;
   pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &handle_client, (void*)cli); 
   //how to call handle_client using s1 object
}
```

The calling function is predefined in pthread.h and the syntax is:

int pthread_create(pthread_t *restrict thread,
const pthread_attr_t *restrict attr,
void *(*start_routine)(void *),
void *restrict arg);

Comment: Use some logic.. to call a function.. you need an operator of function call. To access member of object, what you need? You can't program on instinctive guesses "by analogy"

Comment: What's confusing you here?  `function` is just a member function that returns a `void*`.  `void* some_ptr = s1.function()` is all you need.

Comment: actually am new to coding:
```pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &handle_client, (void*)cli);```
in this function, i want to call the third parameter handle_client whose declaration is like:
```void *handle_client(void *arg)```
using object of a class named serve

Comment: @YashGupta The text in your question says nothing about using `pthread_create`. Your code is there to illustrate your question, not to ask it. An answer like `s1.function();` fits the text of your question. If this is not sufficient, you should be more detailed in the text.

Comment: sorry i wasnt able to add sufficient details, i have updated the question, can u please take a look? @JaMiT

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to call it in main, you need to create an instance of class SERVER to call it. Example:

```
class SERVER
{
   public: 
        void *function()
        {
           return 0; //do whatever you would like in here
        }


};

int main()
{
   SERVER s1;

   s1.function(); 
}
```

Comment: actually am new to coding:
```pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &handle_client, (void*)cli);```
in this function, i want to call the third parameter handle_client whose declaration is like:
```void *handle_client(void *arg)```
using object of a class named serve